# how to run bash script from isolinux.cfg

Tags: linux, bash, boot

I've been trying to add an entry to a bash script to my custom cd boot menu..
So I've tried to edit isolinux.cfg and load it instead of kernel but didn't work..
Any ideas??

Comment: You need to actually boot Linux before you can run `bash`.  There is no shell interpreter available in your pre-boot environment.  Can you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add an entry to a bash script which makes some calculations and 'echo' stuff that runs direct from boot menu